# Implementing 3rd level domain name hosting

Tags: web, dns, hosting

Say, you have a 2nd level domain name of your home town: `my-town.us` and you want to give away 3rd level domain names (like `the-barber.my-town.us`) automatically and for free to anyone requested (i.e. implement 3rd level domain hosting). How would you go about implementing it?

I thought about using wildcard DNS record `*.my-town.us` to point to a web app, which would make a redirect based on requested url. But that would not be any good, because redirect will, well, *redirect* instead of using the desired domain `the-barber.my-town.us`.

Answer (score 1):

You should *delegate* subdomains, just like the domain `my-town.us` was delegated to you.

Just like you supplied contact information and a list of nameservers when you registered `my-town.us`, they should supply contact information and a list of nameservers to you. You then list these nameservers as `NS` records in the parent zone.

Comment: You just create `NS` records for the subdomain in your `my-town.us` zone file. For example, `the-barber   IN   NS   their.nameserver.example.com.`. It's really that simple.

Comment: I guess, that means I need